# Sum up the count

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
Count        Product
100         apple
50          apple
20          orange
```

How can I select to get the sum of the count per product like this?

```
Count         Product
150           apple
20           orange
```

Comment: [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try Query using SUM(),

```
 select SUM(count) as count,Product from #YourTable
 group by Product
```

SUM() function returns the total sum of a numeric column

Answer (score 0):

You should use Aggregate Functions :

```
    select SUM(count) as Count, Product from Product
    group by Product
```

Comment: It says aggregate function calls cannot be nested. what does this mean?

Comment: @user7304434: then you are not running the query shown in this answer